# dua protection from shaytan

Tags: dua, shaitan, protection

I want to know the dua to protect us from shaytan because I remembered shaytan tried to make me late for fajr salah so I want to know the dua to protect me from shaytan

Comment: Somewhat related [At prayer time when reading the kuran can shaitan misguide me](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/46713/at-prayer-time-when-reading-the-kuran-can-shaitan-misguide-me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ٱلسَّلَامُ عَلَيْكُمْ

I suggest that you read some duas/surahs before going to sleep. Here are some you could you read before going to sleep at night.

1. Ayatul Qursi

> Abu Huraira reported: The Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be upon him, ordered me to guard the alms of Ramadan. Then someone came and was stealing from the food. I caught him and said, “I will take you to the Messenger of Allah!” He said to me, “Please do not take me to the Messenger of Allah! I will tell you a few words through which Allah will benefit you! When you go to your bed, then recite the verse of the Throne (2:255) for there will be a guard from Allah to protect you throughout the night and Satan will not come near to you until dawn.” When the Prophet heard this, he said, “He told you the truth although he is a liar, for he was Satan.”

2. The last 3 Surahs of the Quran.

> ‘Ā’ishah (raḍiy Allāhu ‘anhā) narrated that when the Messenger of Allah ﷺ retired to bed every night, he would hold his hands together and then blow into them. He would recite [Sūrah al-Ikhlās, Sūrah al-Falaq and Sūrah al-Nās) ] into them. Then he would wipe them over whatever he could of his body, starting with his head and face and the front of his body, and he would do that three times. (Bukhārī)

3. The last two verses of Surah Al-Baqarah

> I asked Abu Mas’ud while he was making circumambulation of the Ka’bah (about the recitation of some verses from the Qur’an). He said: The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: If anyone recited two verses from the last of Surah al-Baqarah at night, they will be sufficient for him.

Inshallah, Allah will give you the strength to wake up for Fajr and protect at night from Shaitan.

Comment: thank you very much for this answer

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer.
"A'oozu billahi minash shaytan it rajeem"
We always recite this before beginning to read a surah, as protection from Shaytan.
(Translation: I seek refuge to Allah from the accursed Satan)

Answer (score -1):

Another duaa or collection of duaas you could read is manzil. This is a collection of different Surahs put together and people read it to protect themselves from jinns, evil eye, black magic etc.